# How to scrape items correctly in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm currently doing a web scraping project that consists in scraping the products from Delhaize website, their prices and possible discounts. Using my code I'm getting the correct number of products, however there's some products without prices and discounts and to counter that I'm trying to go product by product to try to find the correct number of product's prices. However, I never get the correct amount, either having too many or too litle.

Could you help me? My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from datetime import datetime
import time


myProxy = {
            "http"  : "http://10.120.118.49:8080",
            "https"  : "https://10.120.118.49:8080"
            }

headers={'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}


Product=[]
Price=[]
Discount=[]

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server=http://10.120.118.49:8080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/C71220/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)

for u in range(0,6): 

    url='https://www.delhaize.be/nl-be/shop/Dranken-en-alcohol/c/v2DRI?q=:relevance:manufacturerNameFacet:Coca-Cola:manufacturerNameFacet:Schweppes:manufacturerNameFacet:Fanta:manufacturerNameFacet:Chaudfontaine&sort=relevance&pageNumber=' + str(u)    
    driver.get(url)

    try:
        # makes the scraper wait until the element is loaded on the website
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'data-item')))

        for products in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='description anchor--no-style']"):
            Product.append(products.text.strip('\n'))

        product=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='layout-basket-area']")
        for i in product:

            prices=i.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='quantity-price super-bold']")
            for a in prices:
                if a is not None:
                    Price.append(a.text)
                else:
                    Price.append('')


            promotions=i.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='PromotionStickerWrapper']")
            if promotions is not None:
                Discount.append(promotions)
            else:
                Discount.append(promotions)



        print('Scraping...')

    except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
        pass

print(Product, Price, Discount)
print(len(Product))
print(len(Price))
print(len(Discount))
```

EDIT:

The HTML code for the price is below:

```
<div class="layout-basket-area"...<div>
   <span class="quantity-price super-bold">
```

And for the discount is:

```
<div class="layout-basket-area"...<div>
   <div class="layout-shot">...<div>
       <div class="PromotionStickerWrapper"> title="- 25% voor 2">
```

Comment: Please post all or at least a representative snippet of the HTML you are dealing with. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: I added the html format of the page

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is the message and stack trace?

Comment: One of the answers claims _There were too many errors in the code to fix_, is that accurate? As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were too many errors in the code to fix. I rewrote some parts and added comments. Try this:

```
for u in range(0,6):
    url='https://www.delhaize.be/nl-be/shop/Dranken-en-alcohol/c/v2DRI?q=:relevance:manufacturerNameFacet:Coca-Cola:manufacturerNameFacet:Schweppes:manufacturerNameFacet:Fanta:manufacturerNameFacet:Chaudfontaine&sort=relevance&pageNumber=' + str(u)
    driver.get(url)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'data-item')))

    for product in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("data-item"):
        # get the product list item by class name
        product_name = product.find_element_by_class_name("ProductHeader").text.replace("\n", " - ")
        # try to get the price span by class name with the product list item html else set it to zero
        try:
            product_price = product.find_element_by_class_name("quantity-price").text
            # clean the price by replace € and , and convert it to float
            float_product_price = float(product_price.replace("€","").replace(",","."))
        except NoSuchElementException:
            product_price = "0"
            float_product_price = 0
        # try to get the discount span by class name with the product list item html else set it to zero
        try:
            product_discount = product.find_element_by_class_name("multiLinePromotion").text
            # clean the discount by replace -  %  € and , and convert it to float
            float_product_discount = float (product_discount.replace("- ","").replace("%","").replace("€","").replace(",","."))
        except NoSuchElementException:
            product_discount ="0"
            float_product_discount = 0

        Product.append(product_name)
        Price.append(float_product_price)
        Discount.append(float_product_discount)



print(Product, Price, Discount)
print(len(Product))
print(len(Price))
print(len(Discount))
```